# Synonymize [mail] and [postage] ([post]?)

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging, tag-synonyms

We have both [mail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) and [postage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postage). The tag wiki for [postage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postage) says that it's about post (a.k.a. mail) in general, not just about postage (stamps and pricing), which sounds sensible for me. I think that

- [postage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postage) should be renamed to [post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post)
- [post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post) and [mail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) should be merged

I'd say [mail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) should be the main tag but this may be the Rightpondian in me speaking.

Comment: If we get a consensus on this I'm happy to merge as per consensus. Let's see what @hippietrail has to say as our resident tag expert. :)

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee: I wasn't travelling in April so I was rarely in the neighbourhood. This needs to be fixed (-:

Comment: Done! The mappings should show up now - had to do this from a phone so flag any errors if I made any.

Comment: @pnuts Indeed - but my SO app / Safari keeps crashing whenever I click "Edit" to add tags. Can someone add it for me please? :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Personally I agree with renaming [postage](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/postage) to [post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post) and synonymising [post](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/post) into [mail](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mail) so that the latter becomes the main tag.

Comment: I just found this pair too. I feel embarrassed for our tag garden. "Postage" in English actually means the price of the stamps etc required to mail something. As generic terms "mail" is more universal than "post". But the synonymising is the more important of the two actions.